# What is the origin of 'trunk'?

Tags: svn, trunk

I've always been curious where the name "trunk" for the development branch came from.  This is common with svn repositories, for example.

Comment: The trunk is the thickest part of the tree, from which branches grow out. So it's just part of the tree metaphor: the main line of work. Or are you asking where it was first used in a revision-control context?

Comment: I suppose, in the end, I was asking about what you responded with.  For some reason, I was tied thinking that "trunk" was like a car trunk.

Comment: Ok then, I elaborated a bit and turned it into an answer. Since it answers your question, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark on its left.

Comment: Incidentally there's a mercurial extension called "attic", which is a little like a car trunk-- a place to stash odds and ends. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The trunk is the thickest part of the tree, from which branches grow out. So it's just part of the tree metaphor: the main line of work.

I can't really say when or where the term "trunk" first came into use.  It appears in [CVS documentation](https://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#commit_opts), so it seems to predate SVN (though I suppose the term could have been added to the CVS documentation later.) Note that other common (and newer) revision control systems use different terms: In mercurial it is called `default`, in git it is `master`. These terms seem to de-emphasize the special status of the trunk: As far as distributed revision control systems are concerned, it is just another branch (but it *is* the default branch for certain operations.)